# Remove the containing LI from wordpress widget

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I need to remove the surrounding `li` from a widget that is pulled in with wordpress eg:

```
<li id="dp-twitter-widget-2" class="widget-container widget-twitter">
```

That is the one I need to remove, however it must be server side as javascript manipulates it once it is served, so i would imagine a preg_replace with PHP but I cannot intercept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

test it

```
 $strwithoutli=preg_replace_callback("~<li(.*)>(.*)</li>~si",function($m){print_r($m);return $m[2];}," ".$str." ");
```

for old php version

```
function replace($m){
print_r($m);
return $m[2];
}
$strwithoutli=preg_replace_callback("~<li(.*)>(.*)</li>~si","replace"," ".$str." ");
```

in wordpress widget you didn't need to do this work. you can make change  on  widget  class this is link of class between line 546-555 you can see widget output structure  with make change on this you can remove **li** from output

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/widgets.php#L0

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, im getting `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION`

Comment: @JoshBoothe  what is your php version?

Comment: I believe it is 5.1, using shared web hosting cannot be sure.

Comment: @JoshBoothe i put old version too i recommend you to upgrade php to 5.4.X

Comment: you must set widget output as input of **preg_replace_callback** then show **$strwithoutli**

Comment: @JoshBoothe I make a change on answer. see it